# android: eclipse compile error

Tags: android

I create ninepatch image and copy it into drawable folders, the project becomes error, seems that the file cause error and not supported. I use photoshop to create PNG image then edit it using draw9patch tool.I'm using Eclipse 3.5 on win7 with latest sdk update.

Another thing is that he accept another ninepatch image(titlelogin.9.png), but not accept (logohead.9.png)

Here is my draw9patch image and error image.

[project folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e3xo.jpg)

[logohead.9 img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU5KE.png)

Answer (score 1):

try to press f5 on your package explorer

or try to restart eclipse ,

if don't work and your image is a right ninepatch image make a backup and try Project - clean...

Comment: my friend, i clean all projects and build it but no change

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may be the name of the image .... just try to rename it following the naming conventions of android resources ... for ex. try mypic.png with all letters are lowercased.